# node.js query not returning results but does in mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a function in my controller that is to pull some data:

```
Registration.aggregate([ 
  {$unwind:"$players"},    
  { $lookup: 
  { from: "waiverrecipients", localField: "players.email", foreignField: "email", as: "WAIVERS" } 
},
  {$unwind: "$WAIVERS"}
])
.exec(function(err, registrations) {
  console.log("PLAYERLIST",registrations, err);
if (err) {
  console.log("Error finding registrations", err);
  res.status(500).json(err);
} else {
  console.log("Found " + registrations.length + " registered PLAYERS");
  console.log(registrations);
  res.status(200).json(registrations);
}
});
};
```

When I tested the query in the mongo shell, I literally copied and pasted and used the collection name instead of my mongoose 'Registration' reference:

```
db.registrations.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$players"},    { $lookup:              { from: "waiverrecipients", localField: "players.email", foreignField: "email", as: "WAIVERS" } },{$unwind: "$WAIVERS"} ])
```

The results come up in the mongo shell, but I get status code 200 and a bunch of HTML on the frontend when I try to run this in AngularJS.  Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?